# Temporarily protect email/sms when giving device to others?

Tags: sms, email, gmail, privacy

Say my cousin wants to play with my phone/tablet for a while. Let's pretend I'm really nice and pleased to let him play with it as long as he wants, but deep inside I'm a little worry about him reading my emails and sms out of curiosity. And I have other things to do so I can't stay around and watch.

If the current GMail or SMS applications don't have a 'temporary lock' feature, is it possible to write a separate application that controls access to existing applications on the device? For example, something like "com.google.android.gmail.Main is temporarily protected, draw the correct pattern to open".

Comment: It's crossed my mind when letting others play with my device too.

Answer (score 4):

Give this application a try [App Lock](http://www.appbrain.com/app/app-lock/com.droid.g.applock) you sound be able to lock the application you want to keep private.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the app called "[App Protector](http://market.android.com/details?id=ukzzang.android.app.protector)".

Answer (score 1):

The two best SMS replacement apps - Handcent & GoSMS both have options for putting up a pin input screen before allowing access to the app.

Both also allow this functionality to be extended to the default in-built SMS app as well.

GoSMS also allows a user to apply this security screen to ALL apps, but that tends to hinder rather than help, IMO.